# Compare two text files with two columns, find matches in first column, output match to third file

Tags: regex, awk

I've got two text files.

**file1.txt**

```
AAA example1
BBB example2
CCC example3
DDD example4
```

**file2.txt**

```
FFF example5
AAA example1
BBB example2
GGG example6
```

I want to compare both files first column, and if there's a match then output the whole line from `file1.txt` to `file3.txt` as follows:

**file3.txt**

```
AAA example1
BBB example2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all matches of the second file's first column to the first file's first column, print both columns of the first file where there is a match, then add it to `file3.txt`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' file2.txt file1.txt >> file3.txt
```

Explanation:

`NR` and `FNR` are built in `awk` variables representing the number of total input records and the number of records in the current files.

```
NR==FNR # when in the first file (file2)
{
    a[$1] # build associative array on the first column of file2
    next  # process next line
}
($1 in a) # if value in first column of the second file (file1) is in the array, get the whole line
```

`>> file3.txt` pipes what awk prints to file3.

Comment: You do not need the print section, this should do: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a' file1 file2`

Comment: thanks, updated. The print section is useful if you want to grab specific columns, otherwise if you're grabbing the whole row you don't need it.